# Analytical solution of a convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Which is the analytical solution of the infinite sum  $\frac{1}{1+1^{2}}+\frac{1}{1+2^{2}}+\frac{1}{1+3^{2}}+\frac{1}{1+4^{2}}+\cdots$?

Comment: Is it an university test?

Comment: What's an "analytical solution of an infinite sum"?  (And why does your question say "Which" rather than "What"?) Do you want to know the limit of your series? Or what?

Comment: It seems that you want to know the value of the summation in closed-form, i.e., a closed-form expression of the limit of the partial sums. Although mathematicians are very smart guys, they will not understand (or pretend to not understand) what you are asking until you use the *right* words...

Comment: Anyway, you might want to check Wolfram Alpha (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F(1%2Bn%5E2)+from+1+to+infty ), that gives $(\pi \ \mathrm{cotanh} \ \pi - 1)/2$ as result.

Comment: How we get this result?

Comment: @billmark check my answer!

Answer (score 0):

We start with this identity for the sine function:
$$
\frac{\sinh x}{x} = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{x^2}{k^2\pi^2}\right)
$$

For details on its derivation, check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) article. This product formula was already used to prove another interesting identity involving $\pi$ and infinite series!

Well, we also know that
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \log \sinh x = \coth x.
$$

Due to the properties of the logarithm function, $\log \sinh x$ is
$$
\log x +  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \log \left(1+\frac{x^2}{k^2\pi^2}\right),
$$
therefore,
$$
\coth x = \frac{1}{x} + 2x \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2 \pi^2 + x^2}.
$$

Using $x = \pi$ leads to
$$
\coth \pi = \frac{1}{\pi} + \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2 + 1},
$$
then, solving for the required summation,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2 + 1} = \frac{\pi \coth \pi - 1}{2}.
$$